# How to apply all In clause and fetch the list using criteria in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-criteria

```
  public class RequestClass{
       private String[] a1;
       private String[] a2;
       private String[] a3;
       private String[] a4;
   }
```

```
    public class Entity{
        private String a1;
        private String a2;
        private String a3;
        private String a4;
    }
```

I have a below sql query  to map how to apply criteria to fetch the records using spring JPA

```
select * from entity  where a1 in ('26') 
                      and a2 in ('1','2','3') 
                      and a3 in ('43') 
                      and a4 in ('1');
```

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    
    Root<Entity> root = criteriaQuery.from(Entity.class);
    Expression<String> aExpression = root.get("a1");
    
    Predicate predicate = aExpression.in(RequestClass.geta1());    
    Expression<String> bExpression = root.get("a2");
    
    Predicate predicate = bExpression.in(RequestClass.geta2());   
    Expression<String> cExpression = root.get("a3");
    
    Predicate predicate = cExpression.in(RequestClass.geta3());   
    Expression<String> dExpression = root.get("a4");  
    
    Predicate predicate = dExpression.in(RequestClass.geta4());
```

I have done google but i didn't find solutions

Comment: did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Entity> criteriaQuery = 
                               criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Entity.class);
    Root<Entity> root = criteriaQuery.from(Entity.class);

    Expression<String> aExpression = root.get("a1");
    Predicate predicate1 = aExpression.in(RequestClass.geta1());

    Expression<String> bExpression = root.get("a2");
    Predicate predicate2 = bExpression.in(RequestClass.geta2());

    Expression<String> cExpression = root.get("a3");
    Predicate predicate3 = cExpression.in(RequestClass.geta3());

    Expression<String> dExpression = root.get("a4");  
    Predicate predicate4 = dExpression.in(RequestClass.geta4());

    Predicate andPredicate
      = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate1, predicate2, predicate3, predicate4);

    criteriaQuery.where(andPredicate);
    List<Entity> results = 
                 entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```